# Cross-Platform Deployment Tasks in Bamboo

Tags: continuous-deployment, bamboo

Currently most of my deployments are using a dedicated agent and using Robocopy (windows) or SSH (linux/osx).  A common scenario for my deployments are copying .dlls from a .net project to a server.

I am trying to consolidate capabilities to allow either the windows or linux/osx agents to deploy (using Bamboo).

Is there a simple shared protocol to copy files regardless of the OS or am I correct in assuming I need to setup a solution like OpenSSH on the Windows environment?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a common protocol that exists on all the platforms for deployment.  However, if you get an SSH server onto the windows platforms then you can use the same mechanisms in Bamboo to do the deployment, and potentially even use the same keys to secure it all.

Windows SSHD - There are a few alternatives (https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows).  Freesshd you can get administrator level access - been successfully using it with thousands of machines as old as WinXP for years.

The [Bamboo SCP task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-the-scp-task-in-bamboo-305759795.html) can be used to do the staging to the remote servers - once you have SSH remote access to all your targets.

> You can use the Bamboo SCP task to upload files from Bamboo directly to a remote server as part of a Bamboo job. The SCP task is able to copy multiple files and preserves the directory structure for the copied files.

And [Bamboo SSH task](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-the-ssh-task-in-bamboo-306348532.html) can then do post deployment install steps, running scripts relevant to the platform.

> You can use the Bamboo SSH task to execute a SSH command on a remote computer as part of a Bamboo job.

Comment: Setup an SSHD on your windows platforms - one less hurdle to deal with getting things there.  You SCP things where you want (or worst case SFTP), then run a windows command script to register the DLL, or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: merci for improving your answer, way better ...

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins one has to create a private key and add it to the master. If an agent is called and a build is started, then this key is used. This means that one does NOT have to create a key for every agent. I assume that this should be possible in Bamboo as well. At least that is what I personally expect from a CI/CD system.

Comment: The question has to do with deployments not managing agents though.